# Can't get ngInfiniteScroll to stop scrolling

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation, infinite-scroll, nginfinitescroll

I have a fairly simple web page that I cannot get to work properly. I am using AngularJS, Foundation, and ngInfiniteScroll. With this template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns" style="max-height:500px;overflow-y:scroll">
    <div infinite-scroll="loadMore()" infinite-scroll-distance="0" infinite-scroll-parent="true" infinite-scroll-disabled="loading || !hasMore">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search | orderBy:'-last_modified'">
        <div class="row" ng-click="selectItem(item)">
          <div class="small-3 medium-4 columns text-left">
          <img ng-if="item.thumb2" ng-src="{{ item.thumb }}">
          </div>
          <div class="small-9 medium-8 columns">
            <div> Name: {{ item.name }} </div>
            <div> Last Modified: {{ item.last_modified }} </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear: both;"> &nbsp; </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

... the `loadMore()` function is repeatedly called forever. I have made other similar web pages in the past with nearly identical code and it behaves as expected. For the life of me I can't figure out what's going on here. Is there anything obvious in this code that would lead to `loadMore()` being called even when the page extends well beyond the bottom of the browser window? If not, where can I look next to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you ever found an answer for this, but there was a bug introduced in version 1.2.2 which caused this behaviour. Rolling back to an earlier version (1..0.0) fixed this for me.
More here: https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll/issues/235

Comment: That bug is describing an issue with $interval, which is different from my issue. It's not that i's loading too frequently, it's that it's loading when the bottom element is way past the bottom of the screen (it never stops loading more).

Comment: Strange, that bug described in the issue is certainly not my bug, but rolling back to 1.0.0 did fix it, so some other bug has also been introduced recently.